# Right way of middleware in vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-router

I have created routes in vue, and defined some middleware conditions before each route. But It's not working as I expected.

This is `router/index.js` file.

```js
const token = computed(() => useAuthStore().token);

// Main Router
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'index',
      component: LandingView,
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: LoginView,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (token.value) {
          return next({ name: 'home' });
        }
        next();
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/signup/:uid?',
      name: 'signup',
      component: SignupView,
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: DashboardLayout,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          name: 'home',
          component: HomeView,
        },
        {
          path: 'profile',
          name: 'profile',
          component: ProfileView,
        },
        {
          path: 'deposit',
          name: 'deposit',
          component: DepositView,
        },
        {
          path: 'pay-amount/:amount?',
          name: 'pay-amount',
          component: PayAmountView
        },
        {
          path: 'referral',
          name: 'referral',
          component: ReferralView,
        },
        {
          path: 'salary',
          name: 'salary',
          component: SalaryView,
        },
      ],
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        requiresEmailVerify: true,
        requiresPayment: true,
        requireKyc: true,
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/email-verify',
      name: 'email-verify',
      component: EmailVerifyView,
      meta: { requiresEmailVerify: false },
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (!useAuthStore().email) {
          next({ name: 'login' });
        }
        next();
      },
    },
  ],
});

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const { user, getUserDetails } = useUserStore();

  if (!user?.id && !!token.value) {
    await getUserDetails();
  }
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !token.value) {
    return next({ name: 'login' });
  } else if (to.meta.requiresEmailVerify && !user.email_verified) {
    next({
      name: 'email-verify',
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

router.afterEach(() => {
  const {sidebarVisible, setSidebarVisible} = useLayoutStore();
  if (sidebarVisible) {
    setSidebarVisible(false);
  }
});

export default router;
```

And I'm facing issue in dashboard. If I'm on `/dashboard/deposit` route, and I reload the page then route get changed to `/dashboard`. I think the problem is my middleware that I defined in `router.beforeEach`.

I'm facing the same issue in another route.

I want to stay at same route even if I reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what mode you're running in, From my experiences, Such a problem occurs when nginx is misconfigured.

Comment: I'm facing this issue on localhost. I started server by running `yarn dev` command.